# ruamel.round_trip_dump of a stream adds newline to file

Tags: python, yaml

So I am not sure if this is how a stream acts in general during a dump but I am using ruamel.yaml to do a round-trip change.

So taking my very simple YAML:

```
namespace: default
docker_registry_path: dockerhub/hello
version: 1.0
```

I load the YAML:

```py
for config in ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load_all(stream=open(config_path)):
  ....
  do some magic
  ....

ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(config, sys.stdout))  #prints out with no extra newlines
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(config, stream=open(config_path, 'w'))
```

The console looks great, no extra newlines.  The stream back to the YAML contains an extra newline.  While I can just write a handler that truncates the last line afterwards, I feel this is clunky and either I am dumping wrong or writing with the stream this way is not the way I want to go.

Comment: I don't think it is relevant, but what OS and Python version are you using?

Comment: @Anton, thanks. I should have been more clear on my example yaml that I am reading in, I didn't want to copy/paste the real yaml as it has company specific stuff in it.  The reason for the multiple documents is the header we have in our ansible hosts file that contain comments above a document separator. Those comments are things like company name, author, etc.
I am currently working on a Mac using python 2.7.12.  This eventually will be run on Centos 7.3

Comment: @Anthon looks like its an OS specific issue.  When going over to Centos 7.3, the behavior of round_trip_dump of the stream doesn't add the newline.   I consider this issue resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not presenting a full working program, so it is impossible to see what you are doing wrong. From the code that you do present, I am not sure why you try to read multiple documents from a single document stream.

I assume that after the `0` in your file there is a newline and that you are talking about an extra newline (i.e. an empty line) after that `version: 1.0`, but I cannot reproduce that.

If your three line YAML input document is as indicated and saved in `config.yaml`, and you run the following on Python2 or Python3:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

config_path = "config.yaml"
for config in ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load_all(stream=open(config_path)):
    pass

ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(config, sys.stdout)
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(config, stream=open('abc.yaml', 'w'))

print(repr(open('abc.yaml').read()))
```

you get the same output:

```
namespace: default
docker_registry_path: dockerhub/hello
version: 1.0
'namespace: default\ndocker_registry_path: dockerhub/hello\nversion: 1.0\n'
```

as you can see there is no empty line written to the end of the file.

The only time I have seen an extra newline **on the console** is when people do something like:

```
print(ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(config))
```

or

```
print(ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(config), stream=open('klm.yaml', 'w'))
```

there of course the extra newline is to be expected. If unwanted, they should add `end=''` to the `print` function.

Comment: @Anton so my original yaml has no newline at the end.  The original has 32 lines with no newline.   When I just use a standard logger to print the object it has no newlines, as stated, my dump to sys.stdout looks good too with no newline.  Only when I use the round_trip_dump of the stream do I end up with an extra newline or 33 total lines in the file.  
Sorry for not posting the whole code, had a coworker who asked a question with a full code file and was fired for it. So I'm sensitive about putting all my code in there.

Comment: as you stated above I tried this and you are correct that the extra newlines are done during the prints.  As stated above it looks like my issue is a problem with running python 2.7.12 on OSX (10.12.5) where stream adds a newline to the yaml.  I consider your response as valid solution.  Thank you

Comment: @TripodNH I fully understand that you cannot post your full original code. In that case try to make a minimal example that shows the problem (it often (sometimes that will show the problem so clearly you no longer have to ask on [so] :-) ). Use e.g. `open('klm.yaml', 'w').write(ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(config).rstrip())` if you need to get rid of the trailing newline.

Comment: Thank you so much for that last snippet.  That solves my OSX newline problem and works great on Linux as well.  Such a simple fix with doing the write that way.